# Selenium changes POST request performed by an application

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, web-testing

I have an web application running on localhost, and I try to perform test on it. The app works perfectly and it performs POST request to a different port. However, the application. My chrome driver conf:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost:63342/MyApplication");
```

The application performs request to an addres http://localhost:8991/**requestAddress**
but, on the test it changes address for some reason to:http://localhost:63342/MyApplication/undefined/**requestAddress** but both those URLs should be the same! What has gone wrong?

Comment: Does same problem exist for firefox driver??
what version of chromedriver are U using???

Comment: yes, the problem is problably with the browser, that chromdriver is using. It has complately different local storage, cookies etc, than chrome instance running on my computer. The question now is how to start chrome running on the same session  as the local one.

Comment: In firefox You could copy some files to user profile and start them. It should be also possible in chrome, but that I am not sure.